# Contour integral to real integral: find suitable change of variables

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, contour-integration, substitution

There's probably simple solution but... I have a contour integral of the form $\int _{-i \infty}^{+i \infty} f(t) \ dt$. I want to make a transformation $t = g(s)$ so that the integral is real and of the form: 
\begin{eqnarray} \int_{0}^{\infty} f(g(s)) \ g'(s) \ ds \end{eqnarray}

Thought: the contour $[-i \infty , i \infty]$ is the imaginary axis including the point at infinity, it is geometrically a circle. I'm struggling to find a transformation so that this circle becomes something which is geometrically just a line $[0, \infty]$.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the formula $t=i\log s$ work?  or $t=i(s-1/s)$?

Comment: No, but your answer made me realise that $t=$ exp$\left(\frac{s}{i}\right)$ works, thanks, credit to you! Edit: Oops that's wrong, I had my $s$ and $t$ the wrong way around. No, you are correct :-)